# Merge deduplicates from list of lists

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have list as below.

[('John', 'Johns', 'Jonh'), ('Mark', 'Marke', 'Marken'), ('John', 'Johns', 'Jonh','Johna'), ('James', 'Jame')]

I need to merge deduplicates in another set.

expected output should be as below.

[('Mark', 'Marke', 'Marken'), ('John', 'Johns', 'Jonh','Johna'), ('James', 'Jame')]

Comment: And I tried <HERE_GOES_YOUR_ATTEMPT>. It's not a solve my problem service. It's I tried to solve a problem an encountered an issue, help me out service.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain this is not the most optimal solution, but you can create a new list and iterate over its elements using set operations

```
oldSet = [('John', 'Johns', 'Jonh'), ('Mark', 'Marke', 'Marken'), ('John', 'Johns', 'Jonh','Johna'), ('James', 'Jame')]
newSet = []

for s in oldSet:
    blob = set(s) # I called this blob because it unions with the smaller matching tuples which are then removed
    i = 0
    while i < len(newSet):
        if not blob.isdisjoint(newSet[i]):
            blob = blob.union(newSet[i])
            newSet.remove(newSet[i])
        else:
            i +=1
    newSet.append(blob)

print(str(newSet))
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked on my filtered data, Actually I applied Levenstein matching algorithm. There are some matches not coming in one group due to the distance behavior of the algorithm. I will add incremental number to each set then I will explode into a dataframe column. Thanks for your help.